# How to check if a column exists in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I need to add a specific column if it does not exist. I have something like the following, but it always returns false:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName'
                 AND COLUMN_NAME = 'myColumnName')
```

How can I check if a column exists in a table of the SQL Server database?

Comment: I don't actually think there's anything wrong with the code in the question:  Works finely for me in 2008 R2.  (Maybe you were running it in the wrong database?  Maybe your database was case-sensitive and you didn't have the case right in your myTableName / myColumnName strings?  This type of query seems more flexible than the COL_LENGTH solution:  I'm able to run it against a different database and even over a database link by suitably prefixing "INFORMATION_SCHEMA".  Couldn't see how to do that with the COL_LENGTH metadata-function.

Comment: @mwardm - `COL_LENGTH('AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department ','ModifiedDate')` works fine.

Comment: Little related hint: if you want to update a column right after column addition(I believe many users were searching this article for that purpose), you could use `EXEC sp_executesql` with formed `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: The real answer is you should add the database you are checking against so it's `FROM [YourDatabase].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: You can also use syscolumns and sysobjects very simply.

Answer (score 2370, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 onwards:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'columnName'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'schemaName.tableName'))
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
END
```

Martin Smith's version is shorter:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('schemaName.tableName', 'columnName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
END
```

Comment: In Martin Smith's version, one thing to mention is not to include columnName within square brackets [ ]. When columnName is inside square brackets [ ], it'll give null even if the column exists in the table

Comment: @HemendraSinghChauhan - that's because they aren't part of the name. You will also find that when comparing with the name in `sys.columns`

Comment: @MartinSmith didn't knew that, I was using your answer and came across this. Generally I use square brackets during adding columns, so I used them inside COL_LENGTH function too.

My code was like this:
`Alter table Table_Name
Add [ColumnName] NVarchar(max) NULL;

Select COL_LENGTH('[TABLE_NAME]', '[COLUMN_NAME]')`

Comment: yes that isn't valid. The arguments to `COL_LENGTH` need to be unquoted. It is theoretically possible for someone to create a column that does actually have a name of `[COLUMN_NAME]` - e.g. `CREATE TABLE #T([[COLUMN_NAME]]] INT); SELECT * FROM #T` and then it would be ambiguous if this was not the rule.

Comment: @AlejandroDG Can you provide an example? I would say, this claim is not true.

Comment: AlejandroDG is right. For nvarchar(max):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks


"For varchar columns declared with the max specifier (varchar(max)), COL_LENGTH returns the value -1."

Comment: @sur - So in what sense would that mean "AlejandroDG is right"? The predicate is `IS NOT NULL` not `>0`

Comment: @Shahryar sys.all_columns contains system defined objects AND user objects. Why would you be checking in there?

Answer (score 1153):

A more concise version

```
IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','column_name') IS NULL
BEGIN
/* Column does not exist or caller does not have permission to view the object */
END
```

The point about permissions on viewing metadata applies to all answers, not just this one.

Note that the first parameter table name to [`COL_LENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188732.aspx) can be in one, two, or three part name format as required.

An example referencing a table in a different database is:

```
COL_LENGTH('AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department','ModifiedDate')
```

One difference with this answer, compared to using the metadata views, is that metadata functions, such as `COL_LENGTH`, always only return data about committed changes, irrespective of the isolation level in effect.

Comment: This is less readable than some of the other answers, probably why it's not as highly rated.

Comment: @Bill - Less readable in what way? Looks fine in Firefox. This answer was posted more than 2 years later than the accepted one, which explains the rating IMO. If you meant less clear that it is an existence check this type of idiom is quite common in SQL Server. e.g. using `IF OBJECT_ID('TableName','U') IS NULL` to check object existence or `DB_ID('foo')` to check database existence.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm sure he meant less readable because if you didn't know this idiom, and you inherited this code from someone else, you would not immediately understand what the code does. Kind of like writing `x>>2` instead of `x/4` in C++. The more verbose code (`if exists (select column_name from information_schema ...)`) takes a lot more space, but no one would ever scratch their head trying to figure out what it does.

Comment: Besides more concise this is a way faster solution. Accessing `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views or `sys.columns` hits disk, while `COL_LENGTH` uses cached database metadata.

Comment: This is probably not the most highly rated answer because it was given 2.5 years after the other one. That's why I always check the dates when comparing the ratings on two answers.

It takes a lot longer to overcome an answer that was given much earlier.  ;)

Comment: "_Less readable_" problem solution: `IF COL_LENGTH('Incidente_Incidente','Id_NC_I ') IS NULL /* <--- THIS line checks if column exists in SQL Server table */` ;)

Comment: The select solution requires additional column check for schema scenario. col_length can be used `col_length('schema.table', 'column')`.

Comment: @PasiSavolainen and it accepts three part naming as well. `db_name.schema_name.table_name`. I'll edit my answer to include that explicitly as the three upvotes [on this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table#comment24720735_133031) indicates that not everyone realises...

Comment: @Kip This is true, but in my experience the issue is mitigated by the code that inevitably follows: `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD column_name` :)  Same with the `OBJECT_ID` method.  If that code *doesn't* follow this use of the function, then perhaps some comments (or the expanded syntax in the original answer) is warranted.

Comment: Just needed to use this across our whole fleet - I can confirm this works against SQL 2000 through 2014.

Comment: one thing is to make sure there's no square bracket [ ] in the column name as it gives null every time.

Comment: @HemendraSinghChauhan - no it doesn't. `CREATE TABLE dbo.Test([abc[]]123] int);select * from  dbo.Test;SELECT COL_LENGTH('dbo.Test','abc[]123') `

Comment: @MartinSmith what I meant was that `SELECT COL_LENGTH('dbo.Test','[abc[]123]')` will give NULL. Putting entire columnName in square brackets, in COL_LENGTH gives NULL.

Comment: @HemendraSinghChauhan - that's because the open and closing square brackets aren't part of the name. You would also get the same thing if you tried `SELECT * FROM sys.columns  WHERE name = '[abc[]]123]'`

Comment: 'table_name' should be replaced with 'Schema_name.table_name'

Comment: @PabloClaus Having to put that comment sort of defeats the purpose of being more concise, and I really don't care about whether it's faster as someone else mentioned... I can't imagine any real scenario in the world where that's not negligible because no one is going to write this sort of statement in a loop. But I love being concise so I will totally use this is projects where I am in the one in charge. Will not use when working on other's projects though because I can already here the response "well this isn't consistent with the rest of our application" and that's basically the trump card.

Comment: @MartinSmith - This should be the #1 answer, IMHO.  BWAAA-HAAA-HAAA.... As for the "less readable" comments, if someone who doesn't know this method does and can't figure it out almost instantly when they first come across it insitu, then I'm not sure I'd want them to be the one to do anything with the code.  ;)

Comment: @MartinSmith it gives me an error 
```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'END'. `
``

Comment: @vishal - you need to put your own logic for what you want to do if it does exist between the `BEGIN`  and `END`

Answer (score 178):

Tweak the below to suit your specific requirements:

```
if not exists (select
                     column_name
               from
                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
               where
                     table_name = 'MyTable'
                     and column_name = 'MyColumn')
    alter table MyTable add MyColumn int
```

That should work - take a careful look over your code for stupid mistakes; are you querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA on the same database as your insert is being applied to for example? Do you have a typo in your table/column name in either statement?

Comment: I just found out that adding TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mySchema' after where clause fixes the problem.

Comment: -1: does not answer OP's question, only adds the new information on how to add a new collumn despite OP not asking about that at all, does not address OP's comment.

Comment: +1 Answers OP's question perfectly with a bonus of the additional information the OP was going for next anyways. And this was what I was looking for.

Comment: I mean, this answer does not feel useful to me, because I can not see significant differences between this and the question. Changing `if exists` to `if not exists`, changing `*` to `column_name`, and adding the then branch with `alter table …`, neither of these seem significant. If there is something else in the answer that I missed, maybe the specific difference/suggestion could be written explicitly? HTH

Answer (score 90):

Try this...

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT TOP 1 1
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE 
    [TABLE_NAME] = 'Employees'
    AND [COLUMN_NAME] = 'EmployeeID')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [Employees]
    ADD [EmployeeID] INT NULL
END
```

Comment: This method also works with SQL CE, whereas some of the other methods mentioned do not.

Comment: You can use `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT TOP 1 1` ;).

Comment: Within an `EXISTS` statement SQL automatically optimizes the columns away (much like `count(*)`) so `SELECT *` will suffice.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you should consider adding `and [TABLE_SCHEMA] = '???'` to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 84):

For the people who are checking the column existence before dropping it.

From **SQL Server 2016** you can use new DIE (*Drop If Exists*) statements instead of big `IF` wrappers

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS Column_name
```

Comment: But there isn't a "DIE" in there(?). What is the explanation? Preferably, please clarify it by changing the answer, not here in comments (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Independent, can you link to documentation?

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite of this? like `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS` ?

Answer (score 50):

I'd prefer `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` over a system table because Microsoft does not guarantee to preserve the system tables between versions. For example, `dbo.syscolumns` does still work in SQL Server 2008, but it's deprecated and could be removed at any time in future.

Comment: ["INFORMATION_SCHEMA views could be incomplete since they are not updated for all new features"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx)

Comment: Well yes, that goes without saying since `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views contain only ANSI-standard metadata. However, that is sufficient for an existence test.

Comment: Microsoft says "In future releases of SQL Server, Microsoft may augment the definition of any system catalog view by adding columns to the end of the column list. We recommend against using the syntax SELECT * FROM sys.catalog_view_name in production code because the number of columns returned might change and break your application." That implies that they won't remove columns or change their order. That's good enough backward compatibility for all but edge cases.

Answer (score 44):

You can use the information schema system views to find out pretty much anything about the tables you're interested in:

```
SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

You can also interrogate views, stored procedures and pretty much anything about the database using the Information_schema views.

Comment: This is exactly what the questionnaire is using, he needed to know how to add the column if it did not exist.

Answer (score 35):

Try something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ColumnExists(@TableName varchar(100), @ColumnName varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(1) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result varchar(1);
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName)
BEGIN
    SET @Result = 'T'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Result = 'F'
END
RETURN @Result;
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON  [ColumnExists] TO [whoever]
GO
```

Then use it like this:

```
IF ColumnExists('xxx', 'yyyy') = 'F'
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE xxx
  ADD yyyyy varChar(10) NOT NULL
END
GO
```

It should work on both [SQL Server 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2000) and [SQL Server 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005). I am not sure about [SQL Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008), but I don't see why not.

Answer (score 34):

First check if the `table`/`column`(`id`/`name`) combination exists in `dbo.syscolumns` (an internal SQL Server table that contains field definitions), and if not issue the appropriate `ALTER TABLE` query to add it. For example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    syscolumns
            WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID('Client')
                    AND name = 'Name' ) 
ALTER TABLE Client
ADD Name VARCHAR(64) NULL
```

Answer (score 30):

A good friend and colleague of mine showed me how you can also use an `IF` block with SQL functions `OBJECT_ID` and `COLUMNPROPERTY` in [SQL Server 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005) and later to check for a column. You can use something similar to the following:

[You can see for yourself here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ababc/3):

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myTable]') IS NOT NULL AND
    COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myTable]'), 'ThisColumnDoesNotExist', 'ColumnId') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Column does not exist -- You can add TSQL to add the column here'
END
```

Comment: And of course, if you are confident that the table exists, you can leave out the first part of the condition and check on `COLUMNPROPERTY` only.

Answer (score 26):

```
declare @myColumn   as nvarchar(128)
set @myColumn = 'myColumn'
if not exists (
    select  1
    from    information_schema.columns columns 
    where   columns.table_catalog   = 'myDatabase'
        and columns.table_schema    = 'mySchema' 
        and columns.table_name      = 'myTable' 
        and columns.column_name     = @myColumn
    )
begin
    exec('alter table myDatabase.mySchema.myTable add'
    +'    ['+@myColumn+'] bigint       null')
end
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5183067/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me in SQL Server 2000:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
    AND column_name = 'column_name'
)
BEGIN
...
END
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
SELECT COLUMNS.*
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COLUMNS,
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES TABLES
WHERE  COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME
       AND Upper(COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME) = Upper('column_name')
```

Comment: You don't need `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and you don't filter columns for a specific table, So it sometimes will return more than one row for same column names in separate tables ;).

Answer (score 18):

I needed something similar for SQL Server 2000 and, as [Mitch points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table/133057#133057), this only works in SQL Server 2005 or later.

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
if exists (
    select *
    from
        sysobjects, syscolumns
    where
        sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
        and sysobjects.name = 'table'
        and syscolumns.name = 'column')
```

Answer (score 18):

One of the simplest and understandable solutions is:

```sql
IF COL_LENGTH('Table_Name','Column_Name') IS NULL
  BEGIN
    -- Column Not Exists, implement your logic
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- Column Exists, implement your logic
  END
```

Answer (score 16):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
              FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE table_name = 'TableName'
                    AND table_schema = 'SchemaName'
                    AND column_name = 'ColumnName') BEGIN

  ALTER TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName] ADD [ColumnName] int(1) NOT NULL default '0';

END;
```

Comment: I think you meant table_schema='schema_name'.

Answer (score 14):

```
if exists (
  select * 
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  where TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>' 
  and COLUMN_NAME = '<column_name>'
) begin
  print 'Column you have specified exists'
end else begin
  print 'Column does not exist'
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Do something if the column does not exist:

```
BEGIN
    IF (COL_LENGTH('[dbo].[Table]', 'Column ') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        // Do something
    END
END;
```

Do something if the column does exist:

```
BEGIN
    IF (COL_LENGTH('[dbo].[Table]', 'Column ') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        // Do something
    END
END;
```

Comment: Why is there a space after "Column"?

Answer (score 10):

A temporary table version of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133057/538763):

```
if (exists(select 1
           from tempdb.sys.columns
           where Name = 'columnName'
                 and Object_ID = object_id('tempdb..#tableName')))
begin
...
end
```

Comment: How is that different from the accepted answer? Would a temp table not work in the accepted answer?

Comment: Correct.  The accepted answer does not work for temp tables because 'sys.columns' must be specified as 'tempdb.sys.columns' and the table name must be preceeded by 'tempdb..'.

Answer (score 9):

```
select distinct object_name(sc.id)
from syscolumns sc,sysobjects so  
where sc.name like '%col_name%' and so.type='U'
```

Answer (score 9):

[Wheat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table/133057#133057) is good, but it assumes you do not have any identical table name / column name pairs in any schema or database.  To make it safe for that condition, use this...

```
select *
from Information_Schema.Columns
where Table_Catalog = 'DatabaseName'
  and Table_Schema = 'SchemaName'
  and Table_Name = 'TableName'
  and Column_Name = 'ColumnName'
```

Comment: That is how it should be. With an explanation, not just a "try this" answer.

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to check the existence of a column. 
I would strongly recommend to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` as it is created in order to communicate with user.
Consider following tables:

```
 sys.objects
 sys.columns
```

and even some other access methods available to check `system catalog.`

Also, no need to use `SELECT *`, simply test it by `NULL value`

```
IF EXISTS(
           SELECT NULL 
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE
             TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName'
             AND COLUMN_NAME = 'myColumnName'
         )
```

Comment: No matter even if you `SELECT *` with `EXISTS`, because when exists is used it doesn't really select all the rows and all the columns, internally it just checks for the existence and not actually checks for all rows and columns

Answer (score 7):

Another contribution is the following sample that adds the column if it does not exist.

```
    USE [Northwind]
    GO

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Categories'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Note')
    BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE Categories ADD Note NVARCHAR(800) NULL

    END
    GO
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple script I use to manage addition of columns in the database:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.Columns
        WHERE Name = N'QbId'
            AND Object_Id = Object_Id(N'Driver')
        )
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Driver ADD QbId NVARCHAR(20) NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'QbId is already added on Driver'
END
```

In this example, the `Name` is the `ColumnName` to be added and `Object_Id` is the `TableName`

Answer (score 3):

The below query can be used to check whether searched column exists or not in the table. We can take a decision based on the searched result, also as shown below.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'Y' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = <YourTableName> AND COLUMN_NAME = <YourColumnName>)
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'Column Already Exists.'
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE <YourTableName> ADD <YourColumnName> <DataType>[Size]
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variation...

```
SELECT 
  Count(*) AS existFlag 
FROM 
  sys.columns 
WHERE 
  [name] = N 'ColumnName' 
  AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N 'TableName')
```

Comment: Variation of what? Another answer? [Mike Wheat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table/133057#133057)? Or independent?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? How is it different from the previous answers? What was it tested on (versions, etc.)? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24674846/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

You can check multiple columns in SQLDB at once and return a string as status to check if columns exist:

```
IF EXISTS
        (
          SELECT *
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table Name'
          AND(COLUMN_NAME = 'column 1'
          or COLUMN_NAME = 'column 2'
          or COLUMN_NAME = 'column 3'
          or COLUMN_NAME = 'column 4')
        )
        SELECT 'Column exists in table' AS[Status];
        ELSE
        SELECT 'Column does not exist in table' AS[Status];
```

Answer (score 1):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA work with current database, you must first call "Use [MyDatabase]"

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below query to check if the column exists in the given table:

```
IF(SELECT COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName') IS NOT NULL
PRINT 'Column Exists in the given table';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'Database Name'
and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Schema Name'
and TABLE_NAME = 'Table Name'
and COLUMN_NAME = 'Column Name'
and DATA_TYPE = 'Column Type') -- Where statement lines can be deleted.

BEGIN
  -- Column exists in table
END

ELSE BEGIN
  -- Column does not exist in table
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A simply way to get a result from external program with a query is that:

```
Select case when COL_LENGTH('table_name','column_name') IS NULL then 0 else 1 end as Result;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
      WHERE Name = N'columnName'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'schemaName.tableName'))
```

This should be the fairly easier way and straightforward solution to this problem. I have used this multiple times for similar scenarios. It works like a charm, no doubts on that.

Answer (score -2):

Table → script table as → new windows - you have design script.

Check and find the column name in the new windows.