# Check Column Exist in a Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

How do I check if a column exists in a table using a SQL query? I'm using Access 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Information_schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) views:

```
If Not Exists (Select Column_Name
               From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               Where Table_Name = 'YourTable'
               And Column_Name = 'YourColumn')
begin

-- Column doesn't exist

end
```

In addition, you may want to restrict the `where` clause further by including the Database and/or schema.

```
If Not Exists (Select Column_Name
               From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               Where Table_Name = 'YourTable'
               And Column_Name = 'YourColumn'
               And Table_Catalog = 'YourDatabaseName'
               And Table_Schema = 'YourSchemaName')

begin

-- Column doesn't exist

end
```

Comment: I get the error "SQL instruction not valid. Expeted DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE". Why?

Comment: There is no INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MS Access. This is not a valid answer. INFORMATION_SCHEMA exists in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

```
if Exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'columnName'  
            and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tableName'))

begin

    -- Column Exists

end
```

["REFERENCE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table/133057#133057)

Comment: That would be for SQL Server only - not clear what database the OP is using...

Answer (score 2):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM syscolumns sc
JOIN sysobjects so
ON sc.id = so.id
WHERE so.Name = 'TableName'
AND sc.Name = 'ColumnName')
BEGIN
--- do your stuff
END
```