# Add a column to a table, if it does not already exist

Tags: sql-server, addition, not-exists

I want to write a query for MS SQL Server that adds a column into a table. But I don't want any error display, when I run/execute the following query.

I am using this sort of query to add a table ...

```
IF EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM   sys.objects
       WHERE  OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Person]')
              AND TYPE IN (N'U')
   )
```

But I don't know how to write this query for a column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if column exists in SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table)

Comment: You should use `sys.tables` instead of the "generic" `sys.objects` - then you don't have to specify the type explicitly (it's obvious from the `sys.tables` already....)

Comment: COL_LENGTH Alternative only works from SQL-Server 2008, but it works.

Comment: @MartinSmith very much NOT a duplicate of that. Your link is one possible way to solve it (and indeed, is the recommended way, right now). But the question is actually different and other solutions could be available (e.g. if SQL adds an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to the `ADD COLUMN` syntax)

Comment: @Brondahl - as the question has survived open in the 8.5 years since the comment you are replying to was posted probably no need to panic. At the moment all the answers here are basically dupes of the ones in the linked Q though

Answer (score 305, accepted):

You can use a similar construct by using the `sys.columns` table io `sys.objects`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Person]') 
         AND name = 'ColumnName'
)
```

Comment: Note that in this instance you want to use IF NOT EXISTS in your actual code.

Comment: For optimized query you can use top 1 with select statement

Comment: @BanketeshvarNarayan this is incorrect. The execution plans for subqueries in an `EXISTS` clause are identical. Things like `SELECT 1` or `SELECT TOP 1` are unnecessary. The `EXISTS` clause itself tells the query optimizer to only perform the minimum reads necessary to evaluate the `EXISTS`... at least in SQL Server. Other DB engines may have a more or less efficient query optimizer.

Comment: @BanketeshvarNarayan If you are optimizing your `ADD Column` queries... you must be running them too often!

Comment: I'm confused after Nat's comment.. should we edit the above answer to reflect what he said?

Comment: @user391339 - I have posted a similar construct as OP posted but yes, if you want to take action if the column *doesn't* exist, the statement would be IF NOT EXISTS. I don't really feel the need to edit the answer for this but do feel free to edit yourself if you think it's an improvement.

Comment: How would we check if two columns exist?

Comment: @Kush - Replace `AND = 'ColumnName'` with `AND name in ('ColumnName1', 'ColumnName2')`

Answer (score 148):

```
IF COL_LENGTH('table_name', 'column_name') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD [column_name] INT
END
```

Comment: I tried doing this one but it returns an error which states that COL_LENGTH function does not exist.

Comment: Requires SQL Server 2008+

Comment: Small addition - one shouldn't use square brackets in the column name, since `COL_LENGTH('table_name', '[column_name]')` always return null in SQL Server 2016 (`COL_LENGTH('[table_name]', 'column_name') works as expected`).

Comment: that's because you are essentially quoting the string twice if you put brackets inside single quotes.

Answer (score 45):

Another alternative. I prefer this approach because it is less writing but the two accomplish the same thing.

```
IF COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Person'), 'ColumnName', 'ColumnId') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Person 
    ADD ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
END
```

I also noticed yours is looking for where table does exist that is obviously just this

```
 if COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('dbo.Person'),'ColumnName','ColumnId') is not null
```

Comment: I like it.  I think the best part about posting here is finding gems like this.

Comment: What is 'ColumnId'?

Comment: 'ColumnId' is the name of the column property you are checking against. You could have probably used any property name that exists on a column, such as name, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another variation that worked for me.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE upper(TABLE_NAME) = 'TABLENAME'
        AND upper(COLUMN_NAME) = 'COLUMNNAME')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD Column
END
GO
```

> EDIT:
>   Note that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views may not always be updated, use `SYS.COLUMNS` instead:

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM SYS.COLUMNS....`

Comment: If you're going to edit just edit it to use SYS.COLUMNS not a note to say change the query!

Answer (score 6):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM syscolumns
  WHERE ID=OBJECT_ID('[db].[Employee]') AND NAME='EmpName')
  ALTER TABLE [db].[Employee]
  ADD [EmpName] VARCHAR(10)
GO
```

I Hope this would help. [More info](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/sqlserver/howtoaddcolumnunlessexists.htm)

Comment: This worked for me on SqlServer 2000 while the accepted answer didn't. The sys.* views appear to have been added somewhere around SqlServer 2005, cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/system-compatibility-views-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE  
OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Person]') AND name = 'DateOfBirth')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD DateOfBirth DATETIME
END
```

Answer (score 2):

When checking for a column in another database, you can simply include the database name:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   DatabaseName.sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName]') 
         AND name = 'ColumnName'
)
```