# Insert column if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a new column in my database if it isn't inserted earlier.
My column looks like this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tSafeUnit ADD HasAccess24_7 tinyint not null default 0
```

I want the column to be inserted only if it is not in the table.

My line of code only inserts it but doesn't check if it exists.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Inserting rows is done via `insert` **not** via `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: my mistake, i am trying to insert a new column

Comment: If a column with the same name already exists you'll get an error.

Comment: You want to _add_ a new column to the table.

Comment: [Edit] your post to tag the DBMS being used, then we'll definitely have a duplicate to mark.

Comment: In Postgres you can do `alter table ... add column if not exists ...` - which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: SQL Server: IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tSafeUnit]') 
         AND name = 'HasAccess24_7'
)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a column exists in SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-sql-server-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a column to a table, if it does not already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870802/add-a-column-to-a-table-if-it-does-not-already-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'HasAccess24_7'
AND OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'tSafeUnit') = 0
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tSafeUnit ADD HasAccess24_7 tinyint not null default 0
END
```

Comment: Please note, syscolumns has been deprecated for quite some time now in favor of sys.columns. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscolumns-transact-sql

Comment: And using `IF EXISTS (...)` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` would also be advisable

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS SQL server, then you can do it like below :

```
IF COL_LENGTH('tSafeUnit', 'HasAccess24_7') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tSafeUnit 
    ADD HasAccess24_7 tinyint not null default 0
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'HasAccess24_7' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tSafeUnit')
   AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tSafeUnit')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tSafeUnit ADD HasAccess24_7 TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
END
```

Comment: not accurate at all....  what happen if HasAccess24_7 exists in table tSafeUnit_2 ?

Comment: So what will happen?

Comment: if HasAccess24_7 exists in another table, then  it will not add the new column, you need to make sure HasAccess24_7 doesn't exists in that particular table, and not exists in every table in the database

Comment: hahaha... Just look at the condition "COLUMN_NAME = 'HasAccess24_7' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tSafeUnit'". Coming to "and not exists in every table in the database", why does it matter whether the same column is available in any other table or not. Is it even asked by Endrit Sheholli?

Answer (score -1):

test is the column exists for that table in that schema

```
if not exists ( select 1 
                from information_schema.columns 
                where table_schema = 'dbo' 
                and table_name = 'tSafeUnit' 
                and column_name = 'HasAccess24_7')
begin
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tSafeUnit ADD HasAccess24_7 TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
end
```

Comment: What if tSafeUnit does not exist?

Comment: LOL... its always funny when we don't have any answer :P
Just for your knowledge, it will throw an error...