# How to perform SELECT * in SQL Server to get alias with table name and field at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, alias

Is it possible to get the table name in the alias in addition with the field name using some easy way of `SELECT *` or similar?

Same name of fields in different tables.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (field1 INT, field2 INT)
CREATE TABLE table2 (field1 INT, field2 INT)
CREATE TABLE table3 (field1 INT, field2 INT)
```

If I run a `SELECT *` command

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2, table3
```

I get this kind of result (*example data just showing first row*):

```
field1 field2 field1 field2 field1 field2
-----------------------------------------
1      1      1      1      2      1
```

but I want to get this:

```
table1.field1 table1.field2 table2.field1 table2.field2 table3.field1 table3.field2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             1             1             1             2             1
```

In this example, I can identify better the different value faster with the alias `table3.field1`

**NOTE:**
I don't need to change the `SELECT * FROM` to `SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.* FROM`. In the real case I have almost 20-30 different tables, with almost 10 fields each one of them. So it is not useful for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select unique column names from a list of joined tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474398/select-unique-column-names-from-a-list-of-joined-tables)

Comment: @PeterB not really. It is so close about my question with the table name in the same field.  "T-N" (user's name) already solved my question. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this could only be done using dynamic SQL that builds up the column list based on `information_schema`.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (field1 INT, field2 INT)
CREATE TABLE table2 (field1 INT, field2 INT)
CREATE TABLE table3 (field1 INT, field2 INT)

DECLARE @tables TABLE (seq INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1), name SYSNAME)
INSERT @tables VALUES ('table1'), ('table2'), ('table3')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
    'SELECT '
    + STUFF((
        SELECT ', [' + C.TABLE_NAME + '.' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '] = [' + C.TABLE_NAME + '].[' + C.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
        FROM @tables T
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.name AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
        ORDER BY T.seq, C.ORDINAL_POSITION
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    + CHAR(10) + 'FROM '
    + STUFF((
        SELECT ', [' + T.name + ']'
        FROM @tables T
        ORDER BY T.seq
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')

INSERT table1 VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)
INSERT table2 VALUES (5, 6)
INSERT table3 VALUES (7, 8), (9, 10)

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE table1
DROP TABLE table2
DROP TABLE table3
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT [table1.field1] = [table1].[field1], [table1.field2] = [table1].[field2], [table2.field1] = [table2].[field1], [table2.field2] = [table2].[field2], [table3.field1] = [table3].[field1], [table3.field2] = [table3].[field2]
FROM [table1], [table2], [table3]
```

Output

| table1.field1 | table1.field2 | table2.field1 | table2.field2 | table3.field1 | table3.field2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 10 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 10 |

The `FOR XML PATH('')` construct is a convenient (if not obfuscated) way of concatenating results. The `STUFF()` is used to strip the first comma/space. If you use schemas other than `dbo`, the above would need some enhancements to take that into account. I expect more intelligent `JOIN` logic would also be needed.

Comment: That exactly I needed! In addition, I didn't know the difference between `FOR XML PATH('')` and `STUFF()`. Good to know that. Finally, I will replace the `FROM` part, in order to use the current JOINS

Comment: @JotaPardo, if you are using SQL 2017 or later, you can use `STRING_AGG` instead of the `XML PATH` and `STUFF` ugliness. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax.