# SQL Insert depending if a column exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do one INSERT or another depending if a column exist because of different versions of the same table.

I did the approach at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369176/253329) but SQL Server's pre check or 'sort of compilation' detects an error that would not fail during execution time.

Here's some code

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TableA', 'Column2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])
SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4

END ELSE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]([Column1], [Column3], [Column4])
SELECT value1, value3, value4

END
```

Any workaround?

Comment: where do you get your values? is it some parameters, like @value1...?

Comment: @framara Curious case i tried with the same code but its working , However you can first check for if column exist than go for column length .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL will know that the column doesn't exist so it won't let you run the query. The solution would be to execute a dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @value1 AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @value2 AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @value3 AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @value4 AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @value1 = 'somevalue1'
SET @value2 = 'somevalue2'
SET @value3 = 'somevalue3'
SET @value4 = 'somevalue4'

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

IF COL_LENGTH('TableA', 'Column2') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = 
            'INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])
            SELECT ' + @value1 + ', ' + @value2 + ', ' + @value3 + ', ' + @value4 
    END 
ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = 
            'INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]([Column1], [Column3], [Column4])
            SELECT ' + @value1 + ', ' + @value3 + ', ' + @value4 
    END

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: I finally used the EXEX('INSERT... ') with escape for single quotes. Thanks!

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than approaching this dynamically, I would create stored procedures with a common signature, and add the appropraiate version to your various versions of the database

eg:

```
create proc TableAInsert
(
     @col1 int,
     @col2 int,
     @col3 int,
     @col4 int
)
```

In this fashion, you create an `interface` definition for your database.

If your database changes again, you can create a new version of this procedure with an optional parameter with a default value, and carry on calling it in the same manner as before.

Answer (score 2):

Check if Column2 of TableA exists using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and use that in your original query to switch between the 2 inserts

Answer (score 1):

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEA' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMNNAME')
       BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('TableA', 'Column2') IS NOT NULL
       BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])
    SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4
```

Check first if column exists or not than go check for its length .
However i don't see anything  wrong in checking by `COL_LENGTH`  .

-Hope it helps .