# How use wild card in table name for GetSchema method?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I want query all the existing tables whose name begin with specific string in database using oledb GetSchema method.
In other words I am looking for equivalent of the following sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name  LIKE 'customer%'
```

Something like:

```
String[] tableRestrictions = new String[4];
tableRestrictions[2] = "%customer";
DataTable customerTables = conn.GetSchema("Tables", tableRestrictions );
```

Comment: You can use that query, but you need to execute it like you would any other SQL query (i.e. using a `IDbCommand`).  Not sure why you want to use `GetSchema()`?

Comment: or you can just loop through the schema yourself.  There shouldn't be too many fields.

Comment: @CG: it would return null datatable when I use that query.

Comment: @LarsTech: actually there are too many tables and I want to see what tables exist in the db. Actually the table names are dynamic for some reasons and I should find the name of table before I can query it.

Comment: Then you just make a function where you pass the table name, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the table name I want to query from is Dynamic. Therefore I needed to get the whole table name first.

It seems there is not efficient way to do that but using an iteration.
 I came to this conclusion that using Linq provides the neatest solution(Thanks to [Tim's answer to a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913024/populate-a-list-with-all-the-table-names-which-is-having-specified-columns-throu)):

```
// Get the tables using GetSchema:
dtbTables = dbConnection.GetSchema("tables");

// use linq to get the table whose name matches the criteria:
DataRow recSpecificTable = dbConnection.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
                .Where(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME")
                .StartsWith("customer")).FirstOrDefault();

// Now the table name I am looking for:
tableName = Convert.ToString(recSpecificTable["TABLE_NAME"]).Trim();
```