# Checking existence in mysql query with CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I am using CASE statement in mysql query and I have to check if a column exists or not in the same query.

Is it possible to do so? If yes please help.

My query as example -

SELECT 
CASE column1
WHEN 'status' THEN 'status'
WHEN 'value' THEN 
(select CASE id
WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'status1' ELSE 'status2'
END AS ScheduleStatus
from table1
where condition )
END AS Status
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 
ON ... 
WHERE condition ..;

In above query, when execute it I am getting the result "status2" (else part) even if he condition satisfy.
If the "id" row does not exists at that time the result should be "status1".
Please correct me.

Comment: Show your tried query..

Comment: try this - 
[How to check if column exists in SQL Server table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table

Comment: @idanuda: why do you think a SQL Server specific solution will work for MySQL?

Comment: But I've to check the column inside a nested CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

see the third answer in that page -

```
if not exists (select
                 column_name
           from
                 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
           where
                 table_name = 'MyTable'
                 and column_name = 'MyColumn')
```

it should also work in mySql.

Or you can try this one -

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'columnName'
```

If you want to chack this inside the CASE, do it with a FUNCTION that gets varchar - the column name and return '' or NULL if the column is not exists.
replace the column name with the function-

```
CREATE FUNCTION Func_Check_Exists(columnName CHAR(20)) 
RETURNS CHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 

 RETURN ...;
END;
```

in you code -

```
SELECT CASE Func_Check_Exists('column1') WHEN 'status' THEN ...
```