# How to avoid syntax check before query is run?

Tags: t-sql

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
ColumnA VARCHAR(20),
ColumnB VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO TestTable
SELECT 'TestA', 'TestB'

IF COL_LENGTH('TestTable', 'ColumnC') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ColumnC Present'
    SELECT ColumnC FROM TestTable
END
```

As you can see it should only query ColumnC if it is actually present. However the mgmt studio blocks the execution of the whole query.
Basically what I want is to query for the value of ColumnC if this column exists. I am writing a query for a software on multiple versions, some versions have this column older versions do not.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table

Comment: Not really, the second most popular answer on that question uses the `COL_LENGTH` method he is already using to check for existence.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about how to check for presence of a column. Rather this is about the pre-flight SQL check for names of tables and columns.

I could not figure out how to make the IF ELSE block work so instead I chose to craft a dynamic SQL statement based on the COL_LENGTH.

Here is the actual solution I've used. (my real query uses CTE, so I had to ensure it works fine with CTE as well)

```
DECLARE @IsBroken VARCHAR(20)
SET @IsBroken = 'ColumnB'

IF COL_LENGTH('TestTable', 'ColumnC') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ColumnC Present'
    SET @IsBroken = 'ColumnC'
END

DECLARE @SQLStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLStatement = '
;WITH UpdateTypes AS
(
    SELECT ' + @IsBroken + ' FROM TestTable
)
SELECT * FROM UpdateTypes'
PRINT @SQLStatement
EXEC (@SQLStatement)
```