# SQL If-Drop Statement query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add an IF/DROP Statement similar so the SQL query will run continuously without manual intervention. I need to make sure when I run the query it runs without interference.

Currently I have - which runs fine, but if I want to run it again - it gives me an error: Instance already exists. I want to have a query that checks this instance, drops it if already exists, and creates it.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DATABASE]
ADD [GeoLocation] GEOGRAPHY
```

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to be more descriptive. If you remove the tag information (SQL), your title is *Programming Statement*, which is absolutely meaningless. Your title should describe the question you're asking or the problem you're experiencing in a way that is meaningful, and that will have relevance to future readers here who find it in a search result. While you're at it, you can edit the body of the question to actually ask one. You've stated what you **WANT** to do, but haven't explained what the problem is with the code you've posted or asked a question of any sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if column exists in SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
IF( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TRI_DATA$'
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
      AND COLUMN_NAME = 'GeoLocation' ) = 0
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TRI_DATA$]
ADD [GeoLocation] GEOGRAPHY
```

Comment: Thanks - the only issue I'm experiencing now is, Too many spatial results - please refine your query.