# How to drop column if it exists in PostgreSQL 9+?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to drop a column from a table. How can I check if the column exists or not?

I went through the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altertable.html, but didn't find any example how to do it.

Even found [How to check if a column exists in a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-sql-server-table), but it does not seem relevant.

Comment: The information schema query in the question you link to should work in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You just need to add `IF EXIST` to your `DROP COLUMN` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS columnName;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try via IF EXISTS Method which work great while we are using migration

```
DO $$

BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
    SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = tableName AND column_name = columnName)
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN columnName;
    END IF;

END $$;
```