# If Column exists the drop column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with sql server 2016 syntax for the following                                                                        If columnX exists then drop columnX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a column exists in SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-sql-server-table)

Answer (score 1):

try This

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID INT,
    VAL INT
)

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T') AND Name = 'VAL')
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE dbo.T
    DROP COLUMN VAL

END
```

Comment: and what about if a column is the primary key, it will just drop the column and will not drop CONSTRAINT

Comment: When you drop a column the constraints associated with that will be automatically removed