# Efficient way to check if a row, column etc exists in database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

I have been using the following code to check if a particular row, column, table etc is present in the SQL Server database. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this.
`Note1: I am particularly trying to eliminate using the dataTable dt_local.`
`Note2: I am using C#, WinForms, VS-2015 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.`

```
internal static bool MaujoodHaiKya(string queryLe)
    {
        //This function has been created to check
        //if a particular row, column, table etc exists
        //and to return true or false accordingly
        try
        {
            DataTable dt_local = new DataTable();
            string[] connString = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\MM.ini");

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString[1]))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryLe, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

                conn.Open();
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(dt_local);
            }
            return (true); //Column exists
        }
        catch
        {
            return (false); //Column does not exist
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can probably query the catalog directly (tables metadata) without loading any data

Comment: Or use executereader, and if returned something true, else false

Comment: without knowing what `queryLe` is, it is hard to say how good or bad this is - it could be **horribly** inefficient; but, there's certainly no need to fill a data table with it - heck, just `ExecuteNonQuery` should be sufficient

Comment: TIL 2008 R2 is still in extended support... just about; final cut-off is July 2019, but frankly you should **really, really** be moving as a priority now

Comment: @MarcGravell - I am so sorry. A sample queryLe is `select ACTIV from PRH`

Comment: @MarcGravell / @BugFinder - could you pls elaborate with a small sample piece of code? I am unable to visualise how `ExecuteNonQuery` would be coded for this scenario.

Comment: @PrasadKamath that returns an entire table (all rows), but you just want to check for a single column; frankly, I'd be looking at `sys.columns` for this (or the information-schema stuff), rather than issuing actual data queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet here is probably to use database metadata rather than data queries. Consider:

```
select count(1) as [Count] from sys.columns
where [object_id] = object_id('PRH') and [name] = 'ACTIV'
```

This will return 0 if the column doesn't exist. With that you can use:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
    select count(1) as [Count] from sys.columns
    where [object_id] = object_id('PRH') and [name] = 'ACTIV'";

int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return count == 1;
```

Note that this query can be parameterized if needed:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
    select count(1) as [Count] from sys.columns
    where [object_id] = object_id(@table) and [name] = @column";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", tableName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", columnName);
```

To do the same with information-schema:

```
select COUNT(1) as [Count] from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'PRH' and COLUMN_NAME = 'ACTIV'
```

(which can also be parameterized)

Answer (score 1):

You have some alternative options - which may or may not be more efficient.  The only way to really know for sure is to test it.  Here are two from the top of my head:

1. Use the `COL_LENGTH` T-SQL function to query the database metadata - see if the length of the given column in the given table is NULL or not

   IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','column_name') IS NULL
   BEGIN
    /*Column does not exist or caller does not have permission to view the object*/
   END

   See here for more info: [How to check if a column exists in a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table)
2. Do a simple `"select top 1 * from <tablename>"` query, load it into a datatable and enumerate the fields, check if the one you are looking for was returned.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I said, I would like to use this as a general function to check for many types of things, such as whether a row exists, whether a table exists etc..the comments mentioned in the code were for simplicity, not to be taken literally.