# Is there anyway to check if one field exists in different tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to check if there is one particular field exists in different table using one query only?

For example, I have 3 tables, with many fields. I want to check if field A in table 1 exists in table 2 and table 3.

How can I do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: use EXISTS command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

Answer (score 3):

You can use [COLUMNS view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name = "fieldA_name"
  and table_name in ("table1_name", "table2_name", "table3_name")
```