# check if sql column exists after select query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I have this simple query:

```
  var select = "select * from mainTable where username = '" + username + "'"
```

where I am then checking this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
           if (rows[i]["CHILDTABLEID"] != undefined) {
              //here I need to check if childtable2id has been created within that table yet
   }
  }
```

I need to check if childtable2id has been created within that table yet. How is this possible. I was hoping it wouldn't require a modification to my query, and I could just do something along the lines of:

```
if (rows[I]["CHILDTABLE2ID"]) //check if its been created????
```

if you get where im trying to go with this.

thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what you're trying to achieve? Also, are you trying to see if the table _has a specific column defined in the schema_ or _has a value set in that column_?

Comment: I am basically querying my table, and then wanting to check if a column has been created yet. If the column does not exist in the table, then right now it will just present an error, but I want to be able to add the column if it doesn't exist. Not sure if that helps

Comment: You might be interested in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table to query against the schema for a particular column rather than getting all columns from a `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

If your front end knows it wants CHILDTABLE2ID then it should select it:

```
SELECT CHILDTABLE2ID, ... FROM mainTable WHERE ...
```

One of two things* happens:

- it works
- it errors because the column doesn't exist

Your front end will be able to be coded so it can tell the difference

*well, of course it could error for other reasons.. but the front end will still be able to be programmed to tell the difference