# T-SQL Check if the database contains certain tables and columns MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

**My goal** is to **continue** in the **procedure** **only** with the database selected if it **contains** a **specific** **table** and a specific **column**.

So that I don't get an **error message** later when selecting that this **column doesn't exist**.

Background:
It is the case that database A table A has a more current status than database B with table A. In database B of table A a column is missing, which is the reason for the error that this column does not exist. Which I also do not want to add.

This is my attempt so far:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 
'
use [?]
IF (''?'' NOT LIKE ''%example%'' AND ''?'' NOT LIKE ''%example_two%''
    AND EXISTS(Select 1 from sys.tables where name = ''Table1'') 
    AND EXISTS(Select 1 from sys.tables where name = ''Table2'')
    AND ''?'' NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Database.dbo.Blacklist)
    )
BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT myColumn FROM Table1 Where ID = 5 AND XYZ = 3)) BEGIN.....'
```

Even when i switch instead of

```
..
    AND EXISTS(Select 1 from sys.tables where name = ''Table1'') 
    AND EXISTS(Select 1 from sys.tables where name = ''Table2'')
..
```

To:

```
SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''Table1''
AND COLUMN_NAME = ''MyExample''
```

it will not work the error log outputs: `Incorrect syntax near 'TableXX'.`
The error log gives me all databases that are practically checked, system databases as well.

**Alternative** it would also be helpful if someone knows how to use a case when in the select by trying to store an alternative value once the column does not exist e.g. like this:

```
  'SELECT...
   CASE WHEN exists(
           SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
           TABLE_NAME =''TableX'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''ColumnX'') 
        THEN ''ST.ColumnX''
        ELSE ''0 AS ColumnX''
        END
        FROM ...'
```

I just want to select databases that have the valid table and column, whenever I don't exist I take another table, this works until I find a table where a column doesn't exist, the column is however my select statement therefore I get an error, I want to focus on the alternative question, is there a way to check if the column exists in the current table? before assigning a value?

```
Case WHEN ColumnX exists THEN (ValueOfColumnX) ELSE 0 END AS Column.
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Not with you - you have a stored procedure to which you pass a db name which builds a dynamic sql query and you want to abort/quit the sp if a table and/or column in the selected db is missing (without notification) a simplified example of the sp would be nice.

Comment: I updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one single quotes when you are specifying the names of your tables and columns

```
SELECT 1 FROM your_databasename.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MyExample'
```

If you want to check if a column exists in a table try looking into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-table)